# How to execute a Thread for specific number of times

Tags: java, multithreading

How to execute a Thread for specific number of times. For example i have 4 Threads and Each thread method should be executed for 10 times. How is this possible? And i was instructed not to use loops in run method

I have used something like this. But here it is creating 4 threads and executing for 10 times.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
Runnable worker = new MyThread(i);
executor.execute(worker);
}
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
}
System.out.println("Finished all threads");
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about your requirements. The *correct* design is not to use multiple threads manually but to submit jobs to an executor and not worry about any of the specifics, but your instructor may not know enough to know about that solution and be wanting something else.

Comment: You should replace the while loop with executor.awaitTermination(...). The while loop (called busy-wait) will occupy the CPU, might starve the other threads, drain your battery and eat your lunch.

Comment: @chrylis, i am new to threading concepts and trying to learn. Please excuse if the requirements are not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to read `Java` [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) first.

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

So if you want to run the same `Thread` more than one time is pointless. You should make an new instance of the `Thread` and call start on it.

Comment: here am not trying to start a thread more than once, i have to run, Thread for 10 times.

Comment: @DevRaj: You are probably confusing threads and tasks that run on threads. You don't want to run threads multiple times as they don't work that way, but it's reasonable to run tasks 10 times. These tasks are called `Runnable` in Java

Answer (score 0):

If you literary want each thread running the runnable 10 times, then you probably want to just create 4 separate executors and submit the runnable 10 times, each to the 4 executors.

However this is rather silly because it doesn't matter which thread is executing your runnable. They are all the same. I don't think this is a great exercise.

There are situations (very, very rare) where you want tight control over which thread runs which task etc. but most programmers never need to care.